# abnf parser with node js

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, abnf

Can any one suggest how to parse TEXT using ABNF grammar?

Installed abnf module. 
I have grammar in abc.abnf file.
I have text content in abc.txt file.
I am successful in validating the grammar.
I want content in abc.txt need to validated against abc.abnf grammar.

I just want to convert below text message into Json after parsing/validating...

## Input Text

DMS/6
Dinesh-Sr.Anlayst/12345678
DBMS/PLSQL/JOINS
DATASTRUCTURE/TRESS/GRAPHS

{
    "message": "DMS",
    "version": "6"
    "employee": {
        "name":"dinesh",
        "designation": "Sr,Analyst",
        "contact": "12345678"
    }
    "skills": {
        "dbms": {
            "PLSQL",
            "Joins"
        },
        "datastructure": {
            "Trees",
            "Graphs"
        }     
    }
}

====

## Grammar i tried

DMS =
    MessageInfo
    Employe
e
    Skills;

MessageInfo = MessageIdentifier
    Slant
    Version
    CRLF;

Employee =
    name
    Hyphen
    Designation
    Slant
    contact;
    
Skils = 
        5skill;
        
skill = 
        subject
        expert1
        expert2;

name=10Alpha
Designation=20Alpha
contact=10Numeric
subject=10Alpha
expert1=10Alpha
expert2=10Alpha;

MessageIdentifier                 ="DMS";
Slant   = "/";
CRLF = %x0D;
Version = "5";
Alpha   = %x41-5A;
Hyphen = "-";
Numeric= %x30-39;

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/abnf ? As far as I can see, that only parses the ABNF into "rules"; it does not include any code which would use the rules to parse text. You might want to look at [jison](https://zaa.ch/jison) although that implements yacc/lex style parsing.

Comment: yes, i am using abnf (npmjs.com/package/abnf).

Comment: @rici I have answered your question and updated some more info also. I seen jison, i don't think thats what i expected.. Can you suggest something else as what i written above? (edited)